# How to change the alignment of text in an eleveted button in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the position of the text in this ElevatedButton, how to make it from the center to the right or left

I tried using the TextAlign but it didn't work...

Comment: Can you provide source code of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `style` for `button` and make needed `padding`.

Like in the example below I set `padding` from the left **16** and from the right **0**.

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
          start: 16,
          top: 8,
          end: 0,
          bottom: 8,
        ),
      ),
      child: const Text('Click'),
      onPressed: () {},
    )
```

Result can see in the image below

[image]

Comment: Well it works, but if you try different resulotions you can see the difference

Comment: For this purpose use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil library and you can use **16.dp** instead of raw the value

Answer (score 0):

It's fine I found a solution...

You can use something like this:

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child:
            Text(
                'Button Text',
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color(White), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )
                )),
```